# problems with directing the output of pdfgrep to a file

Tags: grep, emacs, vi, less

I'm trying to search multiple pdf files for a pattern using pdfgrep.    The command I'm using is

```
pdfgrep --color always <pattern> */*.pdf > outputFile
```

I'm directing the output to a file, because the command produces a massive amount of output.    If I then type `cat outputFile` I have a problem with long lines, as the following illustrates, i.e., there a gaps in the lines and some letters and words missing:

```
ARE249/LewandowskyEtAl_PsychSci_2016.pdf:referred to as worldview or cultural cognition—is a major                          because if an overwhelming scientific consensus cannot
ARE249/LewandowskyObenhauerGignac_PsychSci_2016_annot.pdf:referred to as worldview or cultural cognition—is a major                          because if an overwhelming scientific consensus cannot        KIRIVEXIH
ARE249/Lewandowsky_Oberauer_MotivatedRejectionofScience_2016.pdf:apparent than with climate science. The overwhelming                                and Slovic (2013). The tables in panel (a) of Figure 1
ARE249/Lewandowsky_Oberauer_MotivatedRejectionofScience_2016.pdf:    In summary, the rejection of specific scientific evi-                          in panel (b) of Figure 1. Liberals overwhelmingly arrived
ARE249/Lewandowsky_Oberauer_MotivatedRejectionofScience_2016.pdf:to decrease as a result of gun control, whereas they failed                          are motivated to reject an overwhelming scientific con-
ARE249/Mans
```

bridge_SolnsToPolarization_Ch2_annot.pdf:

A related problem is viewing the output file.     If I pipe it to `more`, the output looks ok, but I'd really like to be able to scroll up and down through the output.   However, if I pipe it to `less` I get lots of ESC's, as in

> ESC[35mESC[KARE249/Kahan_VaccineRisk_2014.pdfESC[mESC[KESC[36mESC[K:ESC[mESC[Kone
>   in the PUBLIC_HEALTH scale. The sample-wide scores on that scale
>   reflected an ESC[01;3

An alternative would be to view outputFile through an editor, however in both `vi` and `emacs` I get output similar to the output from `less`.

Does anybody have any good solultions to these problems?   Thanks!

Comment: passing `-R` to `less` should help